# Rewrite phtml file and js file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides

Currently, I have **cc card** HTML in

> MyModule/Testing/view/frontend/web/template/form.html

I want to rewrite this to **phtml** file with my **module** and **js** in **web/js** folder.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that both **`.phtml`** and **`.html`** files are part of the view layer in Magento 2.

The difference is that **`phtml`** files work with **Block** in which according to ***Magento Docs*** is a special PHP class that is usually (but not always) connected to a template.

Blocks usually work with a model layer to manipulate data and return results/response to templates (.phtml or .html files). These files are used by layout files in setting up templates for certain blocks and so on.

**`html`** files on the other end are solely used to display content on the frontend and javascript libraries such as **knockout JS** and use them accordingly. These files are also used for AJAX content loading.
Reference: [Difference between .phtml and .html](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98456/magento-2-html-file-and-phtml-file-in-custom-template-process?answertab=active#tab-top)

In your case, you can convert or rewrite your **form.html** file to **form.phtml** and store it in:

> MyModule/Testing/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

You can then initiate your **.phtml** file in a **layout file** through a layout block.
You can specify your **.phtml** file in the ***`template`*** attribute of the **`<block>`** layout.

Take this example:

> app/code/MyModule/Testing/view/frontend/layout/mymodule_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="mymodule_testing" class="MyModule\Testing\Block\Hello" template="form.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">The Form Template</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

As you can see the **`mymodule_testing`** block is rendered by your ***form.phtml*** template.

Template Reference: [Template Override Magento 2](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html#whats-in-this-topic)

Note: Your layout block has a class named **Hello** which is located in the path ***MyModule\Testing\Block\Hello.php***

Hope this helps or at least gives you an idea or reference to start with.